# PHP Function with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have a question regarding, PHP functions, jQuery and AJAX.
If I have a button in my php index like this:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Download" id="download"/>
```

And I have another php file (dubs.php) that contains this:

```
<?php
function first(){
    echo 'first';
}
function second(){
    echo 'second';  
}
?>
```

And my jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#download").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dubs.php",
        });
    });
});
```

How do I tell my AJAX request to select for example the second function?

I have no idea on how to do this, I've tried it with `"success: first()"` or with `"success: function(){ first() }"` but that did not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your ajax pass some params to identify which function you want to use like this

```
    $("#download").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type   : "POST",//If you are using GET use $_GET to retrive the values in php
            url    : "dubs.php",
            data   : {'func':'first'},
            success: function(res){
              //Do something after successfully completing the request if required
            },
            error:function(){
              //If some error occurs catch it here
            }
        });
    });
```

And in your php file

you can retrive the values in `data` send via ajax and do the following

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && $_POST['func']=='first'){
    first();
}
else{
    second();
}
```

Comment: You'll also need a `success` function to work with the returned data

Comment: Thanks it works, but still one small question: Any idea why it turns into the else statement instead of the if? It runs second(); instead of first(); but I don't see why it does that.

Comment: Can you try var_dump($_POST['func']) to see any spaces are associated with that?.If so use trim() in php to remove spaces.

Comment: It returns NULL, I get the following error: <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: func in <b>C:\Users\user\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\UploadifyZWP\dubs.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br /> NULL

Comment: Give the same key of data in ajax while you use the var_dump().Meaning
if data: {'func':'first'} then var_dump($_POST['func']) same key of data in $_POST.I think you have changed the key in the ajax

Comment: I've found it, the reason why it did not work (my mistake) is that you provided me with code that cointains $_POST while I was using $_GET and I forget to change that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31109/discussion-between-deepu-and-niek-jonkman)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

Your PHP:

```
<?php

function first(){
    echo 'first';
}

function second(){
    echo 'second';  
}



  if (isset($_POST["first"])) first();
  if (isset($_POST["second"])) second(); //add 'else' if needed

?>
```

your jQuery:

```
$.post("dubs.php", {"first":true}, function(result) {
  $("#someDivToShowText").text(result);
});
```

Then, according to the object you send to `$.post`, the php file will know which function to run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your PHP page:

```
<?php

function first(){
    echo 'first';
}

function second(){
    echo 'second';  
}
switch($_POST['func']) {
    case "first":
    first();
    break;
    case "second":
    second();
    break;
    default:
    // Define your default here }
?>
```

and this in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#download").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dubs.php",
            data: {'func':'first'}
        });
    });
```

The `func` variable will tell php which function to run!

});

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try to pass with `data:{func:f1}` and get it on php side and if `f1` is there then fire the first function. Although you can send multiple:

### jQuery:

```
$("#download").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <----stops the page refresh
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dubs.php",
        data:{'func':'f1'}
    });
});
```

### PHP:

```
<?php

  function first(){
     echo 'first';
  }

  function second(){
     echo 'second';  
  }


if(isset($_GET['func']=='f1'){
     first();
}else{
     second();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
$("#download").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dubs.php",
        data: {'function':'first'}
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
call_user_func($_GET['function']);
```

*NOTE*
Be careful with `$_GET` parameters, better check first the contents of `$_GET`