# how to call a function in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my ajax function i have to call function but its not working.any idea how we call using php

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".selectGroup").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State"
    });
});

$("#submit").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"addData.php/get()",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:{
          type:'subject',
          group:$('#selectGroup').val(),
          subject:$('#subject').val(),
        },
        success:function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: And your php trouble is?

Comment: You cannot execute a function like that.. Take a look at my answer here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894192/php-function-with-jquery-ajax/16894262#16894262

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function in :

```
success:function (data) {
    //call your function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of call function in url why not pass parameter in to ajax data. 
Based on parameter value call appropriate function.

```
  $("#submit").click(function (event) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"addData.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:{ type:'subject',
          group:$('#selectGroup').val(),
          subject:$('#subject').val(),
      param:'getCall'
        },
        success:function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

In addData.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['param']) && $_POST['param'] == 'getCall') {
    get();
}

function get() {
    // Function body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#submit").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
       url:"addData.php",
       type:"GET",
       dataType:"text",
       data:{
          type:'subject',
          group:$('#selectGroup').val(),
          subject:$('#subject').val(),
       },
       success:function (data) {
          console.log(data);
       }
   });
});
```

Access your data in PHP using `$_GET['type']`, `$_GET['group']`, and `$_GET['subject']`